# Need to vertically space buttons in scripting C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a prefab and I need to clone that prefab vertically every 100 units from the top. For instance the first clone would be 100 units from top, the second clone would be 200 from the top, 300 from the top etc. The all the prefab are placed on a panel, which serves as a menu for my project. And the menu is scrollable, so some of the clones wouldn't be seen unless the user scrolls. The problem I'm running into is I'm not sure how to position each clone vertically down (i.e. 100, 200, 300 etc). I can't hardcode the values because they'll change depending on the number of cloned items. Is there a method/function that I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how cloning works in unity but I can help you with a simple algorithm to generate the y points you need and hopefully you can use these to clone with unity.

```
const int PREFAB_COUNT = <put your prefab count here>
const int POSITION_OF_TOP = <put position of top here>
for(int i = 0; i < PREFAB_COUNT; i++)
{
    cloneYValue = POSITION_OF_TOP - (i+1)*100;
    //Insert code that codes using cloneYValue as the Y value of the clone

}
```

Also, if I got your coordinate system backwards, you can add the expression to `POSITION_OF_TOP` instead of subtract.

Comment: How do I actually shift the object's position in code?

Comment: basically the Instantiate function

Comment: It should be something like `Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(x,cloneYValue,z), Quaternion.identity);` This is just based on the docs, I don't do unity

Answer (score 0):

Try to use GridLayoutGroup on parent object with those settings:
Constraint: Fixed Row Count
Start Axis: Vertical